# how to solve logcat error?

Tags: java, android

Hi I have created one gallery..I wish to create folder in my gallery. so, I am using file method but now application crash...my emulator display. The application gallery(process gallery.gallery)has stopped unexpectedly. please try again later..how to solve these error...
logcat error:

```
05-05 12:31:09.029: INFO/System.out(333): /mnt/sdcard/myImages
05-05 12:31:09.039: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(333): Shutting down VM
05-05 12:31:09.039: WARN/dalvikvm(333): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught 
exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): java.lang.ClassCastException:   
android.widget.Gallery$LayoutParams
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:934)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at   
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at   
android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at   
android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-05 12:31:09.079: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333):     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: logcat is looooooog.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(85, 85));
```

But the image view takes `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` as argument here. See the [Javadoc for ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29).

Comment: @raja - with a text editor.  Seriously ... what you do is read the javadoc that @Heiko has provided you with, and work it out for yourself.